# Magento 2.0 show custom form for payment method

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, magento2

I have a task which is payment integration with payment gateway.
The payment gateway offering a payment method called COPYandPAY and it works as follows:
https://hyperpay.docs.oppwa.com/tutorials/integration-guide

- Create cURL request from the website to the payment gateway server, this cURL will return a json response with checkout ID.
- Display payment form (in checkout page)using Javascript include.
  3 the form will prompt the user to enter credit card info and the user click submit then done and the user redirected
- so how can I integrate this payment method with magento 2.0?
- is this consider online or offline payment?

  - what is the starting point to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you get a solution? I am lloking for an extesion to integrate HyperPay with Magento 2. Please check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187113/hyperpay-integration-with-magetno-2

Comment: see my answer, if you need extra details let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I worked as follows:
Before begin, I handle this payment as offline payment.

1. Create a basic payment module -> https://mage2gen.com/.
2. In the JS files, add a function that's listen to the radio button of your payment method.
3. on click on this radio you know that's the user chose your payment method, so take the information you need. and send it to a controller in your module that's handle the requests with your payment gateway.

Comment: Can you please give the full code solution ?? Especially the part in js and the controller? and how to add custom field and read this fiels value and do your business before place order? I am new to magento 2 ?